# Doubt Regarding Vectorial summation of electric field

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, electric-fields

So the question was like this :
How many neutral points are possible for a system in which N charges are placed at the N
vertices of a regular N sided polygon? what I am thinking is that we may get many neutral/equilibrium points outside the polygon but we wouldn't get more than one neutral point inside the space enclosed by the polygon and that neutral point is obviously the centroid of the polygon but can anyone prove it mathematically that there lies no more neutral points inside the polygon other than the center. If it is more of a mathematical thing please leave it . 2) There will be many points outside the polygon which can have Electric field zero , How do I get the number of such points and can locate them in the coordinate axis. Sorry If I made any wrong statements, I am to naive , correct me thus.

Comment: Is “N charges” supposed to mean “N *identical* charges”?

Comment: *There will be many points outside the polygon which can have Electric field zero.* Why do you think this?  Can you find even *one*?

Comment: @G.Smith yes N identical charges

Comment: I said I am not sure about anything sorry, I thought If anyone can give something like a mathematical proof about the points that can have electric field zero or if not please prove them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Solution]

I found 5 neutral points for a rectangle and also 4 neutral points for a equilateral triangle , so I was thinking that the answer for N sided polygon would be surely N+1 by my intuition. And there wouldn't be neutral points lying outside the polygon . Am I right?